# What does "-p \; -quit" mean with -exec?

Tags: bash, shell, find

What does `find . exec /bin/bash -p \; -quit` mean?

I already know that when it finds something (a file?) with a `.` it executes `/bin/bash`.

Has  `-p`  something to do with `/bin/bash` or the `find` command?

What does `\;` and `-quit` mean?

Answer (score 17):

```
find . -exec /bin/bash -p \; -quit
```

(which here assumes GNU `find` or compatible for its `-quit`) would start `find`, which would descend the directory tree starting with `.` (the current working directory) and for each file, starting with `.` itself, execute  `/bin/bash -p` (where `\;` is just there to tell `find` where the command to execute ends), and if that command succeeds, exit (because of the `-quit`).

That `find` command in itself doesn't do much useful. It is a convoluted way to start `bash`. Here `-p` can given you a hint as to the (nefarious) intent behind that command.

`-p` would prevent `bash` from dropping its privileges when it's called in a privilege escalation context (like when called from a process that has executed a setuid executable).

It seems like we're in a restricted context where the user is only  allowed to execute a restricted set of commands. That could be a done via a restricted shell for instance.

But `find` happens to be among the list of commands that is allowed and whoever set the restricted  environment up overlooked the fact that `find` can execute arbitrary commands without being affected by the restrictions set against the shell (`find` is not a shell builtin).

So `find . -exec /bin/bash -p \; -quit` looks like the command someone would run to circumvent those restrictions.

Answer (score 6):

The `find` command should actually use the option **`-exec`**, which in turn should end with the escaped semicolon.  That's in all of the manuals for `find`, which explain that the escaping is needed to make it part of the `find` command rather than a separator between shell commands and (for example) not merged with the **`-quit`** option that is shown in your example.

By the way, **`-quit`** appears to refer to some specific implementation (for instance [GNU find](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)), since it doesn't show up in [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html):

> **`-quit`**
>
> Exit immediately (with return value zero if no errors have
> occurred).  This is different to **`-prune`** because **`-prune`** only
> applies to the contents of pruned directories, while **`-quit`**
> simply makes find stop immediately.  No child processes will
> be left running.  Any command lines which have been built by
> **`-exec`** ... `\+` or **`-execdir`** ... `\+` are invoked before the program
> is exited.  After **`-quit`** is executed, no more files specified
> on the command line will be processed.  For example, `find /tmp/foo /tmp/bar -print -quit` will print only `/tmp/foo`.
> One common use of **`-quit`** is to stop searching the file system
> once we have found what we want.  For example, if we want to
> find just a single file we can do this:
>
> `find / -name needle -print -quit`

The `-p` option is documented in [bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash):

> If Bash is started with the effective user (group) id not equal to the real user (group) id, and the **`-p`** option is not supplied, no startup files are read, shell functions are not inherited from the environment, the SHELLOPTS, BASHOPTS, CDPATH, and GLOBIGNORE variables, if they appear in the environment, are ignored, and the effective user id is set to the real user id. If the -p option is supplied at invocation, the startup behavior is the same, but the effective user id is not reset.